# LightSwitch Extension Error - ID already assigned

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to create a LightSwitch Extension for Bing Map

Followed the same steps as in Light Switch Training Kit but in C#. 
Installed the extension. But when I try to add the extension to any LS project / application I get below error.

"Unable o add a reference to this extension for the following reason : Could not load the extension 'BingMapControl'. could not load the extension 'BingMapControl'.Id 'BingMapControl:BingMap is already assigned to another editable model item."

I suspect something wrong in BingMapFactory : IControlFactory
Or is it a completely different problem.

```
private const string ControlTemplate =
        "<DataTemplate" +
        " xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"" +
        " xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"" +
        " xmlns:ctl=\"clr-namespace:BingMapControl.Presentation.Controls;assembly=BingMapControl.Client\">" +
        "<ctl:BingMap Address=\"{Binding Details.Value}\" ApplicationKey=\"{Binding Properties[BingMapControl:BingMap/ApplicationKey]}\"/>" +
        "</DataTemplate>";
```

I re-started VS several times.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you happen to have the Bing map control already in the application, as maybe a custom control?

Comment: I had installed the BingMapControl which comes with LSTraining Kit, but then uninstalled it later. Should that b an issue ?

Comment: Well the error message "Id 'BingMapControl:BingMap is already assigned to another editable model item" would indicate that there's something like that which didn't get cleaned up properly when you ininstalled it. Either that, or you have a duplicate problem in your code.